# Google Map V3 draw polygon and open InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am drawing a polygon dynamically and click to polygon for open InfoWindow.. I am drawing polygon successfully but on click Infowindow doesn't seem. Not gives an error just doesn't seem!

Here is all  my code;

```
       function ADD_EVENT_FOR_POLYLINE_AND_POLYGON () {
            GLOBALS.PolyGonPath = new google.maps.MVCArray;
            GLOBALS.PolyGon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                strokeWeight: 3,
                fillColor: '#5555FF'
            });
            GLOBALS.PolyGon.setMap(GLOBALS.Map);
            google.maps.event.addListener(GLOBALS.Map, 'click', DRAW_POLYGON);
        }


     function DRAW_POLYGON(event) {
        GLOBALS.PolyGonPath.insertAt(GLOBALS.PolyGonPath.length, event.latLng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: event.latLng,
            map: GLOBALS.Map,
            draggable: true
        });
        GLOBALS.PolyMarkers.push(marker);
        marker.setTitle("#" + GLOBALS.PolyGonPath.length);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
            marker.setMap(null);
            for (var i = 0, I = GLOBALS.PolyMarkers.length; i < I && GLOBALS.PolyMarkers[i] != marker; ++i);
            GLOBALS.PolyMarkers.splice(i, 1);
            GLOBALS.PolyGonPath.removeAt(i);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function () {
            for (var i = 0, I = GLOBALS.PolyMarkers.length; i < I && GLOBALS.PolyMarkers[i] != marker; ++i);
            GLOBALS.PolyGonPath.setAt(i, marker.getPosition());
        });

        **Here is I am adding a method to polygon for infowindow**
        GLOBALS.PolyGon.setPaths(new google.maps.MVCArray([GLOBALS.PolyGonPath]));
        google.maps.event.addListener(GLOBALS.PolyGon, 'click', SHOW_INFO);
    },


     function SHOW_INFO (event) {
        var infowin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var vertices = GLOBALS.PolyGon.getPath();
        var contentString = "<b>Test</b><br />";

        for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
            var xy = vertices.getAt(i);
            contentString += "<br />" + "Coordinats: " + i + "<br />" + xy.lat() + "," + xy.lng();
        }
        infowin = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        infowin.setContent(contentString);
        infowin.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowin.open(GLOBALS.Map, this);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the final line of code in your `SHOW_INFO` function from:

```
infowin.setPosition(event.latLng); //Leave this line
infowin.open(GLOBALS.Map, this);
```

to:

```
infowin.setPosition(event.latLng); //This line stays the same
infowin.open( GLOBALS.Map );
```

The second argument to `infowin.open` is an optional `MVCObject` parameter, with a public `position` property, that is used as an anchor. In this case, you don't need to provide an anchor, because you have already called the `infowin.setPosition` method passing a `google.maps.LatLng`. From the `google.maps.InfoWindow`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindow) description of the `open` method:

> Opens this InfoWindow on the given map. Optionally, an InfoWindow can
>   be associated with an anchor. In the core API, the only anchor is the
>   Marker class. However, an anchor can be any MVCObject that exposes the
>   position property and optionally anchorPoint for calculating the
>   pixelOffset (see InfoWindowOptions). The anchorPoint is the offset
>   from the anchor's position to the tip of the InfoWindow.

Comment: ı tired infowin.open( GLOBALS.Map ); but it is same.. doesn seem infowindow.. I clicked to map three times and called ADD_EVENT_FOR_POLYLINE_AND_POLYGON function three times. And draw the triangle(polygon) and  here ı added an event(three times) to polygon google.maps.event.addListener(GLOBALS.PolyGon, 'click', SHOW_INFO);  ı think here is wrong.. how can ı fix?